# Como faço para obter valores de chaves estrangeiras em um formulário JFrame

Tags: java, mysql, jframe

Estou criando um formulário no JFrame para inserir dados em uma tabela que contém duas chaves estrangeiras (Sendo que essas chaves não são geradas automaticamente).

O que tenho que colocar no insert para pegar as chaves estrangeiras?

```
public void inserir(Tratamento tratamento) {
     try{
         try (Connection conexao = getConexao(); PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement("insert into tratamento "
                 + "(codigo_tratamento, titulo,  descricao) "
                 + "values (?,?,?)")) {
             stmt.setString(1, tratamento.getCodigo_tratamento());

             stmt.setString(2, tratamento.getTitulo());

             stmt.setString(3, tratamento.getDescricao());

             stmt.execute();
         }
    }catch(SQLException e){
    }
    //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

Comment: Não entendi bem a pergunta, você quer preencher duas colunas (que são chaves estrangeiras) da tabela tratamento? Ou quer buscar as chaves (sub-select) e preencher no insert? Você tem algo que identifique os dois registros desses relacionamentos (inner join)?

Comment: Buscar as chaves e preencher no insert.

Comment: Quais seriam os elementos ideais da JFrame para fazer a seleção do elemento?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html). Onde cada item da `ComboBox` tem um label e um valor. O valor você pode usar o id para facilitar o `insert`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para preencher o `JComboBox`, basta no contrutor do `JFrame` carregar os possíveis valores através de um `select` e depois criar os Items e adicioná-los à `ComboBox`.

Sendo genérico, o mais simples seria algo como:

```
List<Entidade> entidades = EntidadeDAO.buscar();
this.entidades = entidades; // Variável de instância da classe

JComboBox<Entidade> combo = new JComboBox<Entidade>();
this.combo = combo;

for(Entidade entidade : entidades) {
    combo.addItem(entidade); // Label que será exibida na tela vira do método toString()
}
```

Em algum lugar que execute a ação de inserção:

```
Entidade entidade = this.entidades.get(this.combo.getSelectedIndex());
// ou
Entidade entidade = this.combo.getSelectedItem();

Integer foreignKey = entidade.getId();
// Apartir dai você pode passar a chave estrangeira para a inserção da entidade tratamento.
this.tratamentoDAO.inserir(tratamento, foreignKey, ...);
```

Esse código ficou bem genérico, basta adaptar a seu estilo de programação. Se utilizar MVC, existe o [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) que ajuda a separar a lógica de `view` da lógica do `controller`, nunca usei, mas pode ser útil.